# subtract values of two python dictionaries with the same key

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a couple of python dictionaries

```
dict1 = {0:[('a',10),('b',11),('c',12)],1:[('a',12),('b',15),('c',16)]}
dict2 = {0:[('a',13),('b',15),('c',12)],1:[('a',12),('b',18),('c',20)]}
```

and I'm trying to see if there is an increment in the value of the tuple.

i.e dict1 (a,10) dict2 (a,13), so there's been an increment of 3. The resultant

Expected output:

```
dict3 = {0: ('a',3),('b',4),1:('b',3),('c',4)}
```

My code

```
dict3 = {}
for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(dict1.items(),dict2.items()):
    for va1,va2 in zip(v,v2):
        if abs(int(va1[1])-int(va2[1]) !=0):
            dict3[k] = ((va1[0],abs(int(va1[1])-int(va2[1]))))
```

however is getting overwritten

```
{0: ('b', 4), 1: ('c', 4)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `dict3[k] = ((va1[0],abs(int(va1[1])-int(va2[1]))))` you override the value every iteration, you need to add the new value to the existing instead. You can do it using `get` with an empty list as default value

```
diff = abs(int(va1[1]) - int(va2[1]))
if diff != 0:
    dict3[k] = dict3.get(k, []) + [(va1[0], diff)]
```

Output:

```
{0: [('a', 3), ('b', 4)], 1: [('b', 3), ('c', 4)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create the list structure in your output, so you just overwrite the dict3 value with each new element instead of creating a new item in a list.

Here is an alternative using a dictionary comprehension

```
dict1 = {0:[('a',10),('b',11),('c',12)],1:[('a',12),('b',15),('c',16)]}
dict2 = {0:[('a',13),('b',15),('c',12)],1:[('a',12),('b',18),('c',20)]}

out = {k: [(a, abs(b2-b)) for i, (a ,b) in enumerate(l)
           if (b2:=dict2[k][i][1]) != b]  # walrus operator (python ≥ 3.8)
       for k,l in dict1.items()}
```

output:

```
{0: [('a', 3), ('b', 4)], 1: [('b', 3), ('c', 4)]}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I'm using an older version pf python !

Comment: @psagrera then use `[(a, abs(dict2[k][i][1]-b)) for i, (a ,b) in enumerate(l) if dict2[k][i][1] != b]`, the walrus is not mandatory